# How to search for a specific value and copy range of the below value

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to search a worksheet for a keyword and then copy the range below this value up until a blank line. All of the data is in column A of a worksheet named "Input". The output is to a different spreadsheet named "Stage".

Example of Input Sheet:

```
 A
 Task:                     -> Value I am searching for
 Information I want

 Task:
 Information can be on
 multiple    
 lines                     -> I want to copy all of these lines up until a blank cell
```

Current Code: My current code allows me to copy only the value below the searched word.

```
 Set Stage = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stage")
 Set inputsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

 fnd = "Task:"
 Set myRange = inputsheet.UsedRange
 Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
 Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(What:=fnd, After:=LastCell)


 'Test to see if anything was found
 If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
 FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
 Else
GoTo NothingFound
End If
Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
 Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
'Find next cell with fnd value
 Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(After:=FoundCell)

'Add found cell to rng range variable
 Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)

'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
 If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do

 Loop

 Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
 rng.Copy
 Stage.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the End(xlDown) to collect the additional information lines. Since there will always be at least one line below Task, it can be applied universally.

```
Sub taskGather()
    Dim fnd As String, faddr As String
    Dim rng As Range, foundCell As Range
    Dim sws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sws = .Worksheets("Stage")

        fnd = "Task:"

        With .Worksheets("Input")
            Set foundCell = .Cells.Find(What:=fnd, after:=.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell), _
                                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
                faddr = foundCell.Address
                Set rng = .Range(foundCell, foundCell.End(xlDown))
                Do
                    Set rng = Union(rng, .Range(foundCell, foundCell.End(xlDown)))
                    Set foundCell = .Cells.FindNext(after:=foundCell)
                Loop Until foundCell.Address = faddr

                Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
                rng.Copy Destination:=sws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```